# How to check collision in geometric base classes without casting to derived ones

Tags: c++, inheritance, design-patterns, collision-detection

I've this situation:

```
 class Shape{};
 class Triangle : public Shape{};
 class Rectangle : public Shape{};
 class Square : public Rectangle{};
```

I want to implement a `virtual collideWith` method in the base class that works this way:

```
Shape *square = new Square();
Shape *triangle = new Triangle();

bool test = square.collideWith(triangle);
```

Is there a way to implement this method in order to work with base class without explitit casting do derived classes?

I've thinked to create a namespace that do it:

```
namespace Collision {
  bool isCollisionBetween(const Triangle &triangle, const Square &square) {/* calculus */}
  bool isCollisionBetween(const Rectangle &rect, const Square &square) {/* calculus */}
  // and so on for all combination
}
```

But then I don't know how I can apply this when I have something like

```
std::set<Shape*> shapesSet;
```

and I want to calculate all collision for this set.

Is it possible or it's always necessary to explicity cast `Shape` class to the right inherited one?

Comment: i guess you should make another class named `collisionInformation` and put there data you can compare. than simply compare the returned collision infos...

Comment: You're talking about some enumerator implemented in base class that says "I'm a circle" "I'm a supercomplicatedshapethatyouneverwillseeinyourlife", initialize this member value in derived class and use it to check which `isCollisionBetween` function I should call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general you would solve a problem like this as follows:

1. Give `Shape` an abstract function describing the shape, that each subclass must implement.
2. Each subclass implements this function based on the specific type it is.
3. A `collideWith()` function in `Shape` uses the abstract function of two types to determine the property.

This way when a shape is added, none of the other shapes need to be changed and you don't have to add a function to compare it with each other shape. Only the new shape has to provide functions for all required properties.

Now the difficult part is to decide what property each shape can provide. And in your case it might be difficult to provide it with an efficient implementation.

Examples of properties you can use to provide a collision detection are:

1. `polygonRepresentation()`
2. `asVectorGrahpic()`
3. `convertToBitMap()`

As you can imagine, in your problem, it might be difficult to find a proper representation suitable for each item. Then you probably have to revert to comparisons that know all the elements. But this is really an anti Object Oriented pattern, and will lead to trouble when the amount of shapes or properties increases.

Comment: I know that it can be a not well OO pattern, but in this way I can perform specific collision detection that can be faster that generic ones. I like the idea to convert all shapes in a standard format but in this way I cannot use specific collision algorithms that can be faster than the generic one for polygons (I think about circle-circle collision, for example). So I cannot join the world of dedicated collision detection algorithms and genericity of a base class in a well-formed OO pattern?

Comment: In the end if you want to be really specific you have to resort to knowing the type. You could use multiple abstract properties for the comparison though, although not ideal, it does keep the abstraction: `isCicularShape()` `radius()` could be implemented by all (where `radius()` would return invalid on non circular types, this should you give an 'anti-OO' feeling right away). Then if your comparison has two circular shapes it uses the radius and otherwise falls back to a default implementation. Otherwise I'm afraid you'll fall back to casting.

Comment: Ok I'll think the best way that will fit my problem. Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 2):

ok, my comment was a little bit missleading you. What I meant was:

1. To create the `collisionInformation` make something like a "BroadPhase" (This is optional but very helpful). Consider it as a precheck if potential shapes are colliding. Google therefore "Binary Space Partition". Forget about Quad- or Octtrees at this time. This phase will create a potential contact and their information. Ask your self: which shapes are colliding? which collision resolve function am i calling? Should I use polymorphism or function pointers? (i.e calling a function pointer to a `static bool CollisionResolver::handle( Box b, Circle c );` which can be retrieved/called through `collisoinInformation` ). What callback am I calling if there is a collision? Save all this info to this `collisoinInformation` object
2. Create your different collision handle functions to treat collisions between different shapes. Iterate your i.e `std::vector` saving your `collisionInformation` and call ( a now imaginary function) `colIter->resolve()` which is calling the right implementation of your collision handle functions. If you found a collision ask yourself: Which functions will I call? What information could I provide? i.e stuff additional information into your `collisoinInformation` or maybe create a new object `collisionPair` etc... You could save collision point, normal, the shapes....
3. Collision detection was successfully an is calling "saved" callbacks to your final gameObjects. i.e you could call `GameObject::OnCollision( const ContactPair& p );`

Hope this helps you a little bit more than my previously added comment
ps: A good tip for starters: Look behind the scenes of current open source implementation. i.e [ODE](http://ode-wiki.org/wiki/index.php?title=Manual:_Collision_Detection) or [PhysX](https://developer.nvidia.com/sites/default/files/akamai/physx/Docs/Shapes.html)